# Failed to connect to OpenTok

Tags: opentok

I created a Room chat, used Opentok like this:

in `room.rb` model

```
 require 'opentok'

 def config_opentok
    @opentok ||= OpenTok::OpenTok.new Rails.application.secrets.open_tok_api_key, Rails.application.secrets.open_tok_secret
 end

  def set_opentok_params
    session = config_opentok.create_session
    self.session_id = session.session_id
    self.opentok_token = session.generate_token({
      expire_time: Time.now.to_i + 30.days
      })
  end
```

It worked well but sometimes I got this error:

```
OpenTok::OpenTokError: Failed to connect to OpenTok. Response code: execution expired
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how this should work. The `config_opentok`method doesn't return an OpenTok instance, it assigns one to the instance variable `@opentok`. Can you double check your code snippet?

Comment: @user3621476 did you figure out the problem? I'm having a similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: @montrealmike . Sometimes your server can't connect  to opentok server . So that. try to use it with "while do" loop or "try catch" . :D

Answer (score 1):

```
def config_opentok
        tries = 3
        begin
          @opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new api_key, api_secret
          logger.debug "opentok connected."
         rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e
          log.error e 
          tries -= 1
            if tries > 0
              logger.debug "retrying opentok.new..."
            retry 
            else
              logger.debug "opentok.new timed out..."
              puts "ERROR: #{e.message}" 
            end
          end
        end
```

This worked for me. See also: [Cleanly Retrying Blocks of Code After an Exception in Ruby](http://blog.mirthlab.com/2012/05/25/cleanly-retrying-blocks-of-code-after-an-exception-in-ruby/)